Automating pdf to pdf/A-2b conversion using ghostscript. How to overcome icc color profiling error?
I'm trying to figure out how to convert pdf's to pdfa2b format for archiving. The batch process only takes in 600-800 files at a time, and we have over half a million files. It would take an eternity if we do it one by one (probably 20 months at this rate). Any help is appreciated. Is there a way within Adobe to achieve automation, or would anyone be able to help me point in the right direction with respect to open-source scripts?
Note: Apart from adobe tools, Ive also tried using Ghostscript. I'm hitting a wall with respect to adding the proper color profiles.
PDF VALIDATION ERROR WITHOUT ADDING THE ICC PROFILE:
Device process color used but no PDF/A OutputIntent
                Has Output Intent
                Base color space name
                Outside visible page area

Ghostscript parameters in python:
gs_command = [
    r"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.55.0\bin\gswin64c.exe",  # Full path to the Ghostscript executable
    "-dPDFA=2",
    "-dBATCH",
    "-dNOPAUSE",
    "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite",
    f"-sColorConversionStrategy={color_conversion_strategy}",
    f"-sProcessColorModel={process_color_model}",
    f"-sOutputICCProfile={icc_profile_path}",  # Path to the ICC profile
    "-sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1",
    f"-sOutputFile={output_pdf}",
    input_pdf
]

Error:

Error: /undefined in --runpdf-- Operand stack:   --nostringval--   1
0   --nostringval--   (   **** Error: PDF interpreter encountered an
error processing the file.\n) Execution stack:   %interp_exit
.runexec2   --nostringval--   runpdf   --nostringval--   2
%stopped_push   --nostringval--   runpdf   runpdf   false   1
%stopped_push   1949   1   3   %oparray_pop   1948   1   3
%oparray_pop   1933   1   3   %oparray_pop   1934   1   3
%oparray_pop   runpdf Dictionary stack:   --dict:753/1123(ro)(G)--
--dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:86/200(L)--   --dict:2/10(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: Permission deniedError:
Command
'['D:\Projects\PDFProcessing\packages\gs10.03.1\bin\gswin64c.exe',
'-dPDFA=2', '-dBATCH', '-dNOPAUSE', '-sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK',
'-sDEVICE=pdfwrite', '-sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK',
'-sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK',
'-sOutputICCProfile=../packages/Adobe ICC Profiles (end-user)/Generic
Gray Gamma 2.2 Profile.icc', '-sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1',
'-sOutputFile=../resources/output_pdfa2b.pdf',
'../resources/test.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 1. GPL
Ghostscript 10.03.1: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1 Command output:
None


on versions, thats just a mix up from something I tried in between. Im using 10.03. Well this task is for a non profit library, Im doing this as a side project to figure out if I can help them make it faster. I just started looking into ghostscripts today, so any help is appreciated. i have test file in here - https://github.com/sachins301/PDFProcessing/blob/main/resources/test.pdf

Thank you! I will try to test using their validation script. Going back to library on wed. I did get an A2 file earlier, but that had the validation error I mentioned in the post. but that was without using this color conversion strategy.

You have not used a 'pdfa_def.ps' file, this is a small PostScript program which, among other things, sets the OutputIntent Note, NOT the OutputICCProfile, which you don't want to set and is probably the cause of your error. I'd recommend running Ghostscript from the command line until you get it right, then move that into Python. There is an example pdfa_def.ps file (which you MUST edit) included in ghostpdl/lib, you will also need to grant permission to read the ICC Profile which you include in pdfa_def.ps, by addding --permit-file-read= to the command line.

The documentation for creating a PDF/A file can be found here https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/VectorDevices.html#creating-a-pdf-a-document

PDF/A comes in many flavours but simplest requirements are to remove incompatible objects and add missing fonts, colour "intent" is a more draconian requirement to be avoided if possible.
Thus the simplest GhostScript command is just to run with the PDF/A-2b marks and GhostScript can do that easily with a few instructions.
Using a batch.CMD file for drag and drop or feed with a filename this would be the minimum.
set "GSC=%ProgramFiles%\gs\gs10.03.1\bin\gswin32c.exe"
set "in=%~dpn1.pdf"
set "out=%~dpn1-pdfA-2b.pdf"
"%GSC%" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -dPDFA=2 -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1  -sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndependentColor   -o"%out%" -f "%in%"

Using given test file we can verify it is good

It gets a lot more complex if you need to add colour intents but basically follow the GhostScript documents to edit your own colour profile.PS and include the switch.
So beware after editing any desired profile -switches include with the custom profile.ps.   --permit-file-read=<icc profile name> and or
--permit-file-read="profile.PS" this will avoid any mention of Permission denied

**** Error: Page drawing error occurred.
Could not draw this page at all, page will be missing in the output.
GPL Ghostscript 10.01.2: Unrecoverable error, exit code 255
GPL Ghostscript 10.01.2: Page object was reserved for an Annotation destination, but no such page was drawn, annotation in output will be invalid.
GPL Ghostscript 10.01.2: ERROR: ioerror (-12) on closing pdfwrite device.
Would you know about this error ? i had converted it once earlier, but now its throwing this error.

Oops, I had storage full.  On windows : Systems > Storage > Temporary files (or other files)
